# YAML $ref is not control-clickable (hyperlink) in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, hyperlink, ide, yaml, swagger

We have a .yml file defining the REST API, with many entries like this

```
  /projects/{projectId}/jobs/{jobId}:
    parameters:
      - $ref: '#/parameters/projectId'
      - $ref: '#/parameters/jobId'
    get:
      summary: Get Job
      responses:
        200:
          description: Information retrieved successfully.
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Job'
```

The `$ref` items are not control-clickable in IDEA although they can be.
The YAML and YAML/Ansible support plugins are installed and enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered, with the help of @Frederik here, that the `Swagger Plugin` does the trick. I chose the one by "Zalando" for editing and not for code generation as it has the highest rate.

Answer (score 1):

For me they are control clickable.
But maybe a workaround : use ctrl-B (go to declaration)

Comment: thanks but does not work either. Did you install any plugins?

Comment: Yes, I do have the Swagger plugin installed and the YAML plugin you mentioned

Comment: well Swagger plugin might be it as I don't have it. I'll check.

Comment: and, bingo! Thanks a lot